# Javascript not able to evaluate expression

Tags: javascript, evaluation

I m trying to calculate a day diff in Javascript to apply some value. The first expression

> if subs_start

is working fine, but the second one

> subs_end

is not working, same goes with

> subs_mid

Code:

```
var subs_start = 0;
var subs_mid = 0;
var subs_end = 0;               
var dayDiff = (end_year*365 + end_mon * 30 + end_day) 
            - (start_year*365 + start_mon* 30 + start_day);
var oneDay=1000*60*60*24;
var oneHour = 1000*60*60;
var timeDiff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
var hourDiff = timeDiff/oneHour;
var start_rem_hour = 24 - start_hour*1;

$.each(subsistence, function(id,subs){

    if(subs.start <= start_rem_hour && start_rem_hour < subs.end ){
        subs_start = subs.rate;
    }                   
    alert('T' + end_hour);

    if(subs.start <= end_hour && end_hour < subs.end ){
        subs_end = subs.rate;
        alert ('e ' + subs_end);
    }

    if(dayDiff > 2){
        if(subs.start >= 10){
            subs_mid = subs.rate * (dayDiff - 2);
            alert ('m ' + subs_mid);
        }
    }

}); 

var subs_allow = subs_start*1 + subs_mid*1 + subs_end*1 ;
```

Comment: What is the behavior you expect, and what is going wrong?

Comment: In this case the phrase "is not working" doesn't mean really anything except that you got an answer that you did not expect. What was the data you processed and what is the answer that surprised you? It may even be that it's your expectation that is incorrect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m finally able to find the answer. I need to multiple start_rem_hour and end_hour with 1 to convert into int. It seems js is taking them as string and when i multiply with 1 it gets into integer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is being asked for.

For DateTime calculations in javascript I would recommend **Datejs** library:

http://www.datejs.com/